# How to make interactive Python script with keyboard arrows navigation in menu

Tags: python, interactive, curses

I would like to create interactive Python script (probably using curses?) with menu where user can navigate over menu using keyboard arrows.
What is the easiest way to implement such functionality? Any simple usage/tutorial?
Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

take a look at [Python curses module](http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html) and for example [ncurses-ui-python](http://tuxradar.com/content/code-project-build-ncurses-ui-python).

There are alternatives like [Urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/) and [Pycdk](http://pycdk.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You might wanto to take a look also at [snack](http://www.wanware.com/tsgdocs/snack.html) ([newt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_%28programming_library%29)-based library)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out [Unicurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/), which wraps python's native curses module in linux and pdcurses in Windows.

Unicurses has the benefit of maintaining a style of usage which is consistent with nCurses and PDCurses. Therefore, tutorials such as [this one](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) will be more helpful if you're wrapping puthon curses with unicurses.